# d3 to custom move nodes in DOM

Tags: d3.js

I am working with a svg element, created with d3 as following.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#00b140" stroke="red"></rect>
      <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1020" height="600" fill="none" stroke="#00b140"></rect>
      <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="valLine">
          <path class="Australia" id="valLine" d="M0,600L42.5,600L85,334.0399725781784L127.5,313.86735572781834L212.5,222.9985644559286L255,222.9985644559286L297.5,248.66379557852153L340,248.66379557852153L382.5,248.66379557852153L425,171.66810221073513L467.5,171.66810221073513L510,146.00287108814229L552.5,248.66379557852153L595,248.66379557852153L637.5,248.66379557852153L680,197.33333333333186L722.5,197.33333333333186L765,171.66810221073513L807.5,94.67240884294881L850,94.67240884294881L892.5,94.67240884294881L935,25.495262704563594L977.5,25.495262704563594L1020,0" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="1541.6458740234375 1541.6458740234375"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="movingObjText">
          <text x="1020" y="0">31.13</text>
        </g>
        <g class="fake">          
          <rect fill="white" rx="2.5" x="1014.7325439453125" y="-15.802469253540039" width="43.73328399658203" height="21.06995964050293"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

I am trying to figure out how can I select the class **`body > svg > g > g.fake`** and move that on top of class **`body > svg > g > g.movingObjText`** in DOM so that it results in following

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#00b140" stroke="red"></rect>
      <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1020" height="600" fill="none" stroke="#00b140"></rect>
      <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="valLine">
          <path class="Australia" id="valLine" d="M0,600L42.5,600L85,334.0399725781784L127.5,313.86735572781834L212.5,222.9985644559286L255,222.9985644559286L297.5,248.66379557852153L340,248.66379557852153L382.5,248.66379557852153L425,171.66810221073513L467.5,171.66810221073513L510,146.00287108814229L552.5,248.66379557852153L595,248.66379557852153L637.5,248.66379557852153L680,197.33333333333186L722.5,197.33333333333186L765,171.66810221073513L807.5,94.67240884294881L850,94.67240884294881L892.5,94.67240884294881L935,25.495262704563594L977.5,25.495262704563594L1020,0" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="1541.6458740234375 1541.6458740234375"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="fake">
          <rect fill="white" rx="2.5" x="1014.7325439453125" y="-15.802469253540039" width="43.73328399658203" height="21.06995964050293"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="movingObjText">
          <text x="1020" y="0">31.13</text>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

I came across `selection.insert()` and `selection.raise()`, but I am not sure how to use any of those/ which one of those to achieve the end result I am looking for.

Comment: What's the problem of doing it with `raise()`? Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/bsemhcnj/1/

Comment: Also tackled at the source as `d3.select('.bound').insert('g', 'body > svg > g > g.movingObjText').attr('class', 'fake')..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raise()` seems to work, but you'll need to call it twice to get it at the desired location.

---

I'd recommend using [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), this way you can control the location it's dropped;

So move `.fake` before `.movingObjText` and the text is shown as expected.

```js
let f = document.querySelector('.fake');
let m = document.querySelector('.movingObjText');

f.parentNode.insertBefore(f, m);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#00b140" stroke="red"></rect>
      <rect class="boundRect" x="70" y="70" width="1020" height="600" fill="none" stroke="#00b140"></rect>
      <g class="bound" style="transform: translate(70px, 70px);">
        <g class="valLine">
          <path class="Australia" id="valLine" d="M0,600L42.5,600L85,334.0399725781784L127.5,313.86735572781834L212.5,222.9985644559286L255,222.9985644559286L297.5,248.66379557852153L340,248.66379557852153L382.5,248.66379557852153L425,171.66810221073513L467.5,171.66810221073513L510,146.00287108814229L552.5,248.66379557852153L595,248.66379557852153L637.5,248.66379557852153L680,197.33333333333186L722.5,197.33333333333186L765,171.66810221073513L807.5,94.67240884294881L850,94.67240884294881L892.5,94.67240884294881L935,25.495262704563594L977.5,25.495262704563594L1020,0" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="1541.6458740234375 1541.6458740234375"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="movingObjText">
          <text x="1020" y="0">31.13</text>
        </g>
        <g class="fake">          
          <rect fill="white" rx="2.5" x="1014.7325439453125" y="-15.802469253540039" width="43.73328399658203" height="21.06995964050293"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this and I can definitely use this, but this would probably *break* the d3 chaining. If possible, I want to achieve it with d3 so that the chaining continues.